# What size are the various races?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size

The PHB gives stats for determining height of each race, but I'm particularly interested in the size categories (Small, Medium, Large, etc).  Monster stat blocks list their size category, but I couldn't find anything for player characters.  This is particularly important for the halfling, since some of their race features reference creatures that are a size class larger than them, but I don't know whether the halfling itself is considered small or medium.  Likewise for their fellow party members.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Their size can be found under their *Traits.* Specifically the bold text below their *Alignment* that says **Size.**

Comment: Thanks, I figured it had to be somewhere.  Based on the downvotes, I must be the only one that missed it.

Answer (score 7):

Ditto what Purple Monkey said...
Here's the list to save a few page flips:
Dwarf = Medium
Elf = Medium
Halfling = Small
Human = Medium
Dragonborn = Medium
Gnome = Small
Half-Elf = Medium
Hal-Orc = Medium
Tiefling = Medium